Linux kvm/libvirtd - two video cards - dedicated most powerful GPU to guest via passthrough, what is minimum GPU needed for host?
I am working on setting up my environment so that my workstation runs a Type 1 hypervisor (kvm/qemu/libvirtd). In the past I would just run some base Linux/Windows and use something like Virtualbox, but what I want to do is essentially run all the things I would normally virtualize "next to" my "daily driver".
I am planning to use a minimal NixOS at my host and the run a NixOS as my "daily driver" and then have some other windows vm, containers, etc. running next to them.
My understanding is that I can passthrough my fancy GPU to one of the guest OS but would need to then access the GUI of my host OS through another video card or onboard graphics.
My CPU does not have onboard graphics, so I would need to get a secondary video card to make a setup like this work. My question is, how powerful of a GPU/video card do I really need? In addition, does the second card need to be the same make (e.g., AMD vs Nvidia)?
If I understand correctly, the host is really just a display client and all of the processing happening in my main guest OS with the pass-through GPU is where the power is really needed.
E.g., can I just get some cheap used $25 video card, connect my monitor and it will be good? My understanding is there is no real (officially supported) consumer level way to virtualize the GPU itself.
My goal is to utilize all of this power I have in one box instead of setting up a separate "server" running something like Proxmox. I also want to be able to "reboot" my daily driver without taking down other services on the box, do isolation, etc. which is why I do not want to do Type 2 / virtualbox type setup.
I also wanted to make sure there would be no host-OS issue if the second card happened to be AMD instead of nvidia - honestly, it seems like I just need whatever is cheapest.

Other Info:
Currently what I have in my workstation:
CPU - Ryzen 5950X
GPU - Nvidia 3090
64 GB ram.
Daily Driver / Main Guest will also be Linux/NixOS. I will be running windows, but that will mostly be for hardware comparability with a few things and not gaming, so I want to use the powerful GPU for video editing, etc. I assume if it was really needed, I could "pause" my daily driver and then switch the GPU passthrough to one of the other VMs?

Hold on. What makes KVM a "type 1" hypervisor and VirtualBox not? They both run as drivers in the host OS kernel, they both use CPU hardware virtualization, they're both assisted by user space code for peripheral emulation...

if there is an advantage to using virtualbox and it can do gpu passthrough, sure. I am not partial to any tool.

The minimum GPU needed for the host is none. Many host OS options for VMs are CLI only without a GUI and primarily accessed remotely.
If you plan to use the host OS then you need only as much GPU horsepower as the apps you intend to run on the host OS need (just ensure it will support the resolution of your local display). There's no restrictions on which GPU you select and mixing vendors shouldn't cause an issue. You may want to avoid using the exact same model GPU for your host OS as you do your guest(s), but only to make finding the GUID for passthrough setup slightly easier.
Changing the passed-through GPU back and forth between VMs may not be that challenging, but changing it back and forth between the host and availability for the guests may not work as easily as you imagine.
